# is not abstract and does not override abstract method error

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers

I am totally stuck in one of my classes showing the error:

```
ResettableHttpServletResponse is not abstract and does not override abstract method getHeaderNames() in HttpServletResponse
```

Here is My Entire class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class ResettableHttpServletResponse implements HttpServletResponse, Resettable {

    private interface ResponseOperation {

        void apply();
    }
    private HttpServletResponse wrapped;
    private List<ResponseOperation> operations;
    private Locale locale;
    private int bufferSize;
    private String contentType;
    private String charset;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream;
    private File contents;
    private Set<String> headerNames;
    private int status;
    private boolean stateApplied;

    public ResettableHttpServletResponse(final HttpServletResponse response) {
        wrapped = response;
        operations = new ArrayList<ResponseOperation>();
        headerNames = new HashSet<String>();
        resetState();
    }

    @Override
    public void addCookie(final Cookie cookie) {
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addDateHeader(final String name, final long date) {
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.addDateHeader(name, date);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addHeader(final String name, final String value) {
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.addHeader(name, value);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addIntHeader(final String name, final int value) {
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.addIntHeader(name, value);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void applyState() {
        try {
            // Apply all operations
            for (final ResponseOperation operation : operations) {
                operation.apply();
            }
            // Copy the response contents, if any
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.flush();
                    IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(contents), wrapped.getOutputStream());
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    throw new NestableRuntimeException(e);
                }
            } else if (writer != null) {
                try {
                    writer.flush();
                    IOUtils.copy(new FileReader(contents), wrapped.getWriter());
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    throw new NestableRuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            stateApplied = true;
        } finally {
            reset();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsHeader(final String name) {
        return headerNames.contains(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String encodeRedirectUrl(final String url) {
        return wrapped.encodeRedirectUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public String encodeRedirectURL(final String url) {
        return wrapped.encodeRedirectURL(url);
    }

    @Override
    public String encodeUrl(final String url) {
        return wrapped.encodeUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public String encodeURL(final String url) {
        return wrapped.encodeURL(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        // No-op, as nothing has been done in the real response
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferSize() {
        return bufferSize;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCharacterEncoding() {
        return charset;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    @Override
    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getWriter() was already invoked in this response");
        }
        if (servletOutputStream == null) {
            contents = File.createTempFile("cyclos_", "_response");
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(contents);
            servletOutputStream = new ServletOutputStream() {
                @Override
                public void close() throws IOException {
                    outputStream.close();
                }

                @Override
                public void flush() throws IOException {
                    outputStream.flush();
                }

                @Override
                public void write(final byte[] b) throws IOException {
                    outputStream.write(b);
                }

                @Override
                public void write(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) throws IOException {
                    outputStream.write(b, off, len);
                }

                @Override
                public void write(final int b) throws IOException {
                    outputStream.write(b);
                }
            };
        }
        return servletOutputStream;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getOutputStream() was already invoked");
        }
        if (writer == null) {
            contents = File.createTempFile("cyclos_", "_response");
            writer = new PrintWriter(contents);
        }
        return writer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCommitted() {
        if (!stateApplied) {
            return false;
        }
        return wrapped.isCommitted();
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        resetState();
    }

    @Override
    public void resetBuffer() {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(writer);
        outputStream = null;
        servletOutputStream = null;
        writer = null;
        if (contents != null) {
            contents.delete();
            contents = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resetState() {
        status = 0;
        operations.clear();
        headerNames.clear();
        charset = wrapped.getCharacterEncoding();
        bufferSize = wrapped.getBufferSize();
        contentType = wrapped.getContentType();
        locale = wrapped.getLocale();
        resetBuffer();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendError(final int sc) {
        status = sc;
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                try {
                    wrapped.sendError(sc);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new NestableRuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void sendError(final int sc, final String msg) throws IOException {
        status = sc;
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                try {
                    wrapped.sendError(sc, msg);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new NestableRuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(final String location) throws IOException {
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                try {
                    wrapped.sendRedirect(location);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new NestableRuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setBufferSize(final int bufferSize) {
        this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.setBufferSize(bufferSize);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setCharacterEncoding(final String charset) {
        this.charset = charset;
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.setCharacterEncoding(charset);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentLength(final int len) {
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.setContentLength(len);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentType(final String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.setContentType(contentType);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setDateHeader(final String name, final long date) {
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.setDateHeader(name, date);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeader(final String name, final String value) {
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.setHeader(name, value);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setIntHeader(final String name, final int value) {
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.setIntHeader(name, value);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocale(final Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.setLocale(locale);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setStatus(final int sc) {
        status = sc;
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.setStatus(sc);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setStatus(final int sc, final String sm) {
        status = sc;
        operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
            @Override
            public void apply() {
                wrapped.setStatus(sc, sm);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any one tell me what I am supposed to do to get rid of this error?

**EDIT: I have added the following Method declaration in the Class but it does not seem to be affecting my error. What exactly should I do?**

```
@Override
public Collection<String> getHeaderNames() {
    operations.add(new ResponseOperation() {
        @Override
        public void apply() {
            wrapped.getHeaderNames();
        }
    });
    return headerNames;
}
```

Comment: The signature of the method is `java.util.Collection<java.lang.String> getHeaderNames()`.

Comment: See My Edit .. Am getting Same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you implement an interface to a class which isn't abstract, you have to redefine all the methods declared in the interface. Here you did'nt redefine the method `getHeaderNames()` declared in the interface `HttpServletResponse`.

You need to override this method in your class `ResettableHttpServletResponse`

**EDIT :**

The error you get is explicit. It clearly says that you forgot to override the method [`getHeaderNames`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeaderNames%28%29) of the interface `HttpServletResponse`.

You should read the [lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) about interfaces and inheritance.

Comment: Am getting `method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`

Comment: I have checked the interface HttpServletResponse. It does not even have a method `getHeaderNames` declared

Comment: There is a method. Check this : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeaderNames()

Comment: See My Edit, I cannot seem to get my head around thins :(

Comment: the method `getHeaderNames` has no params.

Comment: I have removed the `final String name` param but the Error is still persistent. :(

Comment: You have to return an object of type `Collection` which contains `String objects`. For example, you can return an `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: Sir, what I have returned is the headerNames which is of type `Set<String> headerNames;` and then instantiated `headerNames = new HashSet<String>();` See My Edit

Comment: Declare `headerNames` as an `HashSet<String>`

Comment: Done that .. The error is still here. Is there anything I need to Change?

Comment: `ResettableHttpServletResponse is not abstract and does not override abstract method getHeaders(String) in HttpServletResponse`

Comment: You need to implement the method `getHeaders(String name);` too (it's a different method than `getHeadersName()`). Please take a look at the interface : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

Comment: I wish to Thank you for Openning My eyes to the Differences. There was getHeaders, getHeader and getHeaderNames method .....Thanks it worked now.

Answer (score 0):

The abstract class or interface (this case) HttpServletResponse defines an abstract method `getHeaderNames()` which you did not implement. As your class is not abstract too, that is an error. Often the IDE can generate a dummy implementation for all abstract methods.

You might consider using [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) instead.